# Showing a big margin between each row item in recyclerview with grid layout manager

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I have the following XML which I inflate into a Recyclerview with a grid layout manager -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_product_title"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_description_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/products_row_item_product_description" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/very_light_grey"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/products_row_item_price_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_heart_image_view"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/like_heart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_likes"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the XML looks like this on my phone -

[image]

But the result I want to achieve is for the UI to have a much bigger margins, making the feeling that the row items are "swimming" inside them. Here is a demonstration -

[image]

So my questions are the following -

1) How do I change my XML file to look the same as the wanted one? 
2) As you can see, the heart & like icons are stuck together with the price label. I want to separate them like the picture.

Comment: add margins in your item layout

Comment: You need to add margins in your root LinearLayout (item layout) Instead of padding.
Remove applied item decorater from your recyclerview.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. please comment and I will approve. What fixed it was Vivek's comment about margins in the row item layout.